# Succulent's older and outer rim leaves are yellowing/dying

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, succulents

Sorry I forgot the name of this succulent. Previously 1 leaf used to yellow and wither away but this time I noticed 5 leaves are yellowing, and all are older leaves. Last time i water this succulent was 2 weeks ago

| top | and a side view |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

By the way it also has one pup growing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is evidence of white fungal growth on one or two leaves, possibly mildew; you can spray with a fungicide or try baking soda mixed with horticultural oil, see this link [White Mold in Succulents](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/white-mold-succulents-44105.html).

In the meantime, try to improve air flow round the plant - check any other succulent plants you have indoors and separate it away from those if they are not infected. This plant appears to be a variety of *Echeveria.*

Comment: sounds bad, unfortunately neither i have horticultural oil neither neem oil. But i order today from amazon but it will be shipped from outside of KSA 4-5March ,unfortunately couldn't find on any nursery . But how about i clean the leaves with damp clothes ?

Comment: Milk spray or bicarb spray might be worth a try - if you have baking soda (bicarbonate of soda in the UK) mix 2 parts of that with 8 parts water in a spray bottle and spray with it. Or do it with dairy milk, 2 parts milk to 8 parts water and spray, whichever you've got handy at home.

Comment: Never knew there is something called Milk spray , one can learn new things everyday. Love this community. thanks. And yes i have bicarbonate of soda , but as @Colin Beckingham mentioned , im thinking to wait for few weeks. because im 90% sure after reading more about this plant that this succulent uses "white powder" to protect itself from intense sunlight.

Comment: There's a reason why you're losing leaves and its mildew - its clearly visible in two images above - in the first image, there's a leaf to the left with white fluffy deposits on its tip, and in the second image, that leaf is pointing directly towards you (centre of the pic) with deposits on the tip showing as white bumps. So unless only this leaf/leaves has been exposed to intense sunlight and the others haven't,  its mildew. Check it closely with a magnifying glass before deciding to leave it untreated. Also, if you spray, it should be a fine spray, like a light mist, ,not sufficient to soak.

Comment: Thanks @Bamboo , i will follow your advice of "if you have baking soda (bicarbonate of soda in the UK) mix 2 parts of that with 8 parts water in a spray bottle and spray with it" , i will let update you

Comment: If it doesn't, use neem or horticultural oil when you get some...

Answer (score 1):

Your succulent looks quite normal for a mature plant. The leaves are plump, fat and healthy, showing some of the dusty bloom that they use to protect themselves from intense sunlight. The reddish tips are also normal for a high light plant, and the fact that a pup has appeared and some outside leaves are dying off indicates that its interior chemistry is changing over to flower and seed production mode.

No action required, sit back and enjoy the flowers when the inflorescence emerges. Learn to judge water requirements by how inflated the leaves are. Puffy leaves means no water required.